# angularjs controller and modules

Tags: angularjs, module, controllers

I am initiating me in AngularJS and I have a doubt beginner.

I have defined my main module with several units already displayed on screen . I happen to have another module but do not know how to put it in the main module , because if I put it as a dependency , then the view gives me error. I have also doubts how to apply various ngcontroller in html, because the same thing happens , if I put the main everything works fine ... when I put the second module , and nothing works ... I guess that is dependence.

I leave my code and you will understand better. Thank you very much.

JS code ----------------------------------------------------

```
var app = angular.module('frutariaApp',
    ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia) {
```

(this is the part I don't know to implement over de main module).

```
   angular.module('acc-test', ['ui.bootstrap']);
   function AccordionCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.oneAtATime = true;
     }
});
```

HTML---------------------------

```
<html ng-app="frutariaApp">
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <div class="accordion-test" ng-controller="AccordionCtrl"> //Ihave problem with this too   
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">    
    <accordion-group is-open="falsee">      
        <accordion-heading>
            Number <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
             <ul>
          <li><a href="#">0</a></li>
            <li>1</li>          
      </ul>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: what is `'acc-test'` doing in your code?. And why have you defined `AccordionCtrl` when you have already defined `AppCtrl`

Comment: why do you want to use bootstrap and angular material together?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use modules other than the main one they must be injected as a dependency of another module.

Try injecting your `'acc-test'` module into the main app module

```
var app = angular.module('frutariaApp',    ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'acc-test']);
```

Comment: And the rest of code will be the same?? I mean, I continuos need this part of code? or angular.module('acc-test) dissapear??...
 (angular.module('acc-test', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function AccordionCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
})

Comment: Yes... can have as many modules as you want and as long as each one is injected as dependency of at least one other then they are all combined into one `app`. Then use any controller.... and can also use any service from any of the modules in other modules also since they are all one big app